# How to update Laravel Installer for version 8.x?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-upgrade

I used this command for installing **Laravel** Installer:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

For creating a project I use :

```
laravel new name --jet
```

on 8th September `laravel 8.x` was released, and I'm looking for installing it using the laravel command but I couldn't do it. Instead, a new laravel project was created with Laravel 7.x. I need some help.

Note: I can create a project with `Laravel 8.x` with this command, but I need to update my required Laravel and make a project with laravel 8.x and jetstream by using the laravel command:

The `Error` looks like this.....

[image: Click Here to see error]

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/updating-the-laravel-installer

Comment: Please post the error in plain test in a code block too.

Comment: What have you tried so far to update the installer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between composer update and composer global update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577455/difference-between-composer-update-and-composer-global-update)

Answer (score 0):

It will work

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel
composer require laravel/jetstream
php artisan jetstream:install inertia
```

Comment: it's worked but laravel will remove the composer installation that's why I need the installer

Comment: @TarikManoar what does that mean? "laravel will remove the composer installation"?

Answer (score 0):

`/home/example_username/.config/composer` go to this folder

and edit `composer.json`

and put

```json
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/installer": "^4.0"
    }
}
```

then run `composer global update`

Comment: Yes, I do that but after the update installer when I type `laravel --version` it shows me the old one like 3.x

Comment: @TarikManoar u need to restart `cmd` or `pc` after this

Comment: @TarikManoar then check your `/home/example_username/.config/composer`  here `composer.json` file what version is showing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update your php version to >7.3 and latest Laravel Installer 4.0.3

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Comment: Please share some more explanation such that others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful: https://laravel-news.com/reminder-update-your-laravel-installer

> To see what version you have installed run laravel -V in your console
> and if it’s less than v4.0 you’ll need to update, and we have a
> tutorial on doing it, but typically it’s just a matter of running:

`composer global require "laravel/installer:^4.0"`